# How to remove cling?

Tags: macos, clang, cling

After run clang --version on my MAC OS 10.15 Catalina, I got this result:

```
clang version 5.0.0 (http://root.cern.ch/git/clang.git 7fd3024be56d751958d68ea3abeca4ab2f89dd91) (http://root.cern.ch/git/llvm.git e0b472e46eb5861570497c2b9efabf96f2d4a485)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/user/cling/bin
```

When I use cmake, it keeps using the clang installed by cling.
Now I get errors when compile c++ code with header file cmath.h included. How to uninstall cling and use Apple clang?

Comment: `which clang` will reveal the directory it resides. This should give you a hint how to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the install was self-contained as shown, you can get rid of it with:

```
rm -r  /Users/user/cling
```

Then you’ll want to remove whatever got into PATH to point you to cling.